# Python: global name re is not defined in the function

Tags: python

I am relatively new to python and I am stumped by this error.
I have a python script with three classes which imports re at the start. But when I try to use re.search or re.sub within a function in the class it gives me the error "global name re is not defined ". This is resolved when I write import re within the method.

What am I doing wrong?

```
import re
class Temp:
    def pluginSysLog(self):
        import re
        folderName= "plugin" 
        fileName=inspect.stack()[1][1].split("/")[len(inspect.stack()[1][1].split("/"))-1]                
        logObject = temp.loggerSetup("logObject", "/"+folderName+"/"+re.sub(".py",".log",fileName))       
        return logObject
```

Error

```
File "./temp.py", line 151, in pluginSysLog
    logObject = temp.loggerSetup("logObject", "/"+folderName+"/"+re.sub(".py",".log",fileName))       
NameError: global name 're' is not defined
```

Comment: I'd be quite interested in seeing a [mcve] that produces this error.

Comment: Show the original (faulty) code.

Comment: Where's the code where you call `pluginSysLog()`? Is the function call included in the same file or a separate file?

Comment: I call pluginSysLog() from another script. i have included import re in that script also.

Comment: You need to show a self-contained example demonstrating the problem.  Probably your `import re` is not really at the top level (i.e., it's actually indented under a class or something).

Comment: Your error message is not generated by the code you posted (based solely on the change from `detective` to `temp`). Show the code that actually produces the error.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure without more code, but:

1) If you've imported re at the top of the file, at the global level, you don't need to re-import within any classes or functions in that file

2) Be careful you haven't created any variables, function parameters, member variables, etc. with the name "re".

Comment: 1) I have imported re at the top. That is why I am confused about the error.   2) I don't have any variables named re.